# Inheritance and casting with templates not working as expected

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting, polymorphism

I've been playing around with template and inheritance but there is something strange about using virtual function members with template parameters when performing a cast to the base class. They seem to work using "direct inheritance" but not if I "defer" the inheritance later on.

A bit of code to illustrate:

Example [1]

```
struct CastExBase
  {
  virtual void f() {}
  };

template<class RT>
struct CastExA : CastExBase
  {
  void f() {std::cout << "CastExA" << std::endl;}
  virtual void g() {std::cout << "g - A" << std::endl;}
  virtual RT h() {std::cout << "h - A" << std::endl;}
  };

struct CastExB
  {
  void execF() {std::cout << "CastExB" << std::endl;}
  void g() {std::cout << "g - B" << std::endl;}
  int h() {std::cout << "h - B" << std::endl;}
  };

struct CastExC :
    public CastExA<int>,
    protected CastExB
  {
  void f() override
    {
    (static_cast<CastExB*>(this))->execF();
    }

  void g() override
    {
    (static_cast<CastExB*>(this))->g();
    }
  };
```

Test case:

```
  CastExBase* a2 = new CastExC();
  CastExA<int>* a3 = (CastExA<int>*) a2;
  a3->g(); // This prints g - B as expected
  a3->h(); // This prints h - A ... why???
```

Why a3->h() does not print h - B?

I tried also another test directly inheriting from the base class and in this case it correctly works.

Example [2]

```
struct CastExDBase
      {
      };

    template<class T>
    struct CastExD : CastExDBase
      {
      virtual T f() {std::cout << "CastExD" << std::endl;}
      };

    struct CastExE : CastExD<int>
      {
      int f() {std::cout << "CastExE" << std::endl;}
      };
```

Test case:

```
  CastExDBase* d1 = new CastExE();
  CastExD<int>* d2 = (CastExD<int>*) d1;
  d2->f(); // This prints CastExE as expected
```

Is this related to UB?

Comment: `CastExA<int>* a3 = (CastExA<int>*) a2;` - You cannot downcast with a C-style cast, you need to `dynamic_cast` here.

Comment: ideally yes but I know that the type will be CastExA<int>* so should be ok to use it. Anyway, I tried also to dynamic cast it but same result

Comment: General tip: Never do C-style casts in C++. If you ever need to do it it's usually a red flag that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Yep, I should have used static_cast, I agree

Comment: Closely related, possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19528338/how-to-override-a-function-in-another-base-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if `CastExC` inherits both `CastExA<int>` and `CstExB`, the definition of `h()` in `CstExB` will not override the "definition" of `h()` in `CastExA<int>` because `CastExA<int>` and `CstExB` are not related. If you try to do this:

```
CastExBase* a2 = new CastExC();
CastExC* a3 = (CastExC*) a2;
a3->h();
```

You will get an ambiguous request for `h()`. If you want to overload, you need to do this manually:

```cpp
struct CastExC: protected CastExB, public CastExA<int> {
    virtual int h() override { return CastExB::h(); }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no `h()` in `CastExC`. Maybe that's why.

*Note: `CastExA` and `CastExB` are not related.*

Comment: Damn it was indeed that... as always the simplest solution... thank you